# How can I manipulate a web page (re-arranging some HTML controls) through the Browser?

Tags: devtools

I want to be able to open my website and use some kind of firefox plugin to re-arrange some Html on the site by drag-and-drop and be able to use that modified source. I used to use a css plug-in but do not remember it anymore. Are there any cool tools or plugins avaiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not drag-and-drop, but [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) will let you modify any web page in Firefox. You'll have to edit the HTML/CSS source directly, though; once you're done, you should be able to copy and paste into a text editor.

Comment: Firebug is one of those tools that you use once and wonder how you ever got things done without it.